# I am trying to convert my categorical values to integers, boolean variables to integers to feed into my model for training

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have 2 boolean, 14 categorical and one numerical value

```
def data_pipeline(df):
    #Normalizes and converts data and returns dataframe
    bool_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=np.bool).columns
    num_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns
    cat_cols = list(set(df.columns) - set(num_cols))
    # Normalize Numeric Data
    df[num_cols] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df[num_cols])
    # Convert categorical variables to integers
    df[cat_cols] = df[cat_cols].apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
     # Convert boolean variables to integers
    df[bool_cols] = df[bool_cols].astype(int)
    return df

##I am trying to train the aforementioned features.

train_features_prepared = data_pipeline(train_features)
```

Raises:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py in _encode(values, uniques, encode, check_unknown)
    112         try:
--> 113             res = _encode_python(values, uniques, encode)
    114         except TypeError:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py in _encode_python(values, uniques, encode)
     60     if uniques is None:
---> 61         uniques = sorted(set(values))
     62         uniques = np.array(uniques, dtype=values.dtype)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


    258 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py in _encode(values, uniques, encode, check_unknown)
    115             types = sorted(t.__qualname__
    116                            for t in set(type(v) for v in values))
--> 117             raise TypeError("Encoders require their input to be uniformly "
    118                             f"strings or numbers. Got {types}")
    119         return res

TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['float', 'str']
```

Comment: `cat_cols` is populated with all the columns minus `num_cols`, so it includes the two boolean series... could you try `cat_cols = [colname for colname in df.columns if colname not in num_cols and colname not in bool_cols]`?

Comment: Thanks Richie! I tried with the aforementioned code. Same error, unfortunately.

Comment: how about `cat_cols = df.select_dtypes('category').columns` ?

Comment: Hold on... what are you trying to do with `LabelEncoder()` ? That method is supposed to work on 1-D target arrays... your category columns should be processed with `OneHotEncoder` or `OrdinalEncoder`, both from the same `sklearn.preprocessing` API

Comment: I was trying to normalize the label but I reckon you are correct in regards to the LabelEncoder(). It looks like the above code  cat_cols = df.select_dtypes('category').columns  worked but now its giving me an error after running the training code              ##[' Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=['0013' '0021' '0903' ... '0041' '0130' '0002'].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample'.}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to preprocess your category features you need to use `OneHotEncoder` or `OrdinalEncoder` as per comments.

Here is an example of how to do that:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml


X = fetch_openml('titanic', version=1, as_frame=True).frame
X.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1309 entries, 0 to 1308
Data columns (total 14 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------     --------------  -----
 0   pclass     1309 non-null   float64
 1   survived   1309 non-null   category
 2   name       1309 non-null   object
 3   sex        1309 non-null   category
 4   age        1046 non-null   float64
 5   sibsp      1309 non-null   float64
 6   parch      1309 non-null   float64
 7   ticket     1309 non-null   object
 8   fare       1308 non-null   float64
 9   cabin      295 non-null    object
 10  embarked   1307 non-null   category
 11  boat       486 non-null    object
 12  body       121 non-null    float64
 13  home.dest  745 non-null    object
dtypes: category(3), float64(6), object(5)
memory usage: 116.7+ KB
```

```
cat_cols = X.select_dtypes('category').columns

# choose what to do with NaNs, dropping just for this example
X.dropna(subset=cat_cols, inplace=True)

# filter category columns
X_cats = X.select_dtypes('category')
X = X.drop(X_cats.columns, axis=1)
X_cats.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1307 entries, 0 to 1308
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------    --------------  -----
 0   survived  1307 non-null   category
 1   sex       1307 non-null   category
 2   embarked  1307 non-null   category
dtypes: category(3)
memory usage: 14.3 KB
```

```
# instantiate encoder and get dummies
enc = OneHotEncoder().fit(X_cats)
X_cats_encoded = pd.DataFrame(
    enc.transform(X_cats).toarray(),
    columns=enc.get_feature_names(cat_cols)
)

# join with other features
X = pd.concat([X, X_cats_encoded], axis=1)
```

Output

```
X.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1309 entries, 0 to 1308
Data columns (total 18 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------      --------------  -----
 0   pclass      1307 non-null   float64
 1   name        1307 non-null   object
 2   age         1044 non-null   float64
 3   sibsp       1307 non-null   float64
 4   parch       1307 non-null   float64
 5   ticket      1307 non-null   object
 6   fare        1306 non-null   float64
 7   cabin       293 non-null    object
 8   boat        484 non-null    object
 9   body        121 non-null    float64
 10  home.dest   744 non-null    object
 11  survived_0  1307 non-null   float64
 12  survived_1  1307 non-null   float64
 13  sex_female  1307 non-null   float64
 14  sex_male    1307 non-null   float64
 15  embarked_C  1307 non-null   float64
 16  embarked_Q  1307 non-null   float64
 17  embarked_S  1307 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(13), object(5)
memory usage: 194.3+ KB

print(X_cats_encoded)
      survived_0  survived_1  sex_female  sex_male  embarked_C  embarked_Q  embarked_S
0            0.0         1.0         1.0       0.0         0.0         0.0         1.0
1            0.0         1.0         0.0       1.0         0.0         0.0         1.0
2            1.0         0.0         1.0       0.0         0.0         0.0         1.0
3            1.0         0.0         0.0       1.0         0.0         0.0         1.0
4            1.0         0.0         1.0       0.0         0.0         0.0         1.0
...          ...         ...         ...       ...         ...         ...         ...
1302         1.0         0.0         1.0       0.0         1.0         0.0         0.0
1303         1.0         0.0         1.0       0.0         1.0         0.0         0.0
1304         1.0         0.0         0.0       1.0         1.0         0.0         0.0
1305         1.0         0.0         0.0       1.0         1.0         0.0         0.0
1306         1.0         0.0         0.0       1.0         0.0         0.0         1.0

[1307 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Brilliant! I'll give it a shot. Thanks! Cheers!